# Executing and delaying array of promises in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to execute a series of functions synchronousl usingy. Each function is supposed to be delayed by 3 seconds before invoking the next one.
I must be doing something wrong because they are all invoked at the same time after 3 seconds instead of in order.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
var tasks = []
    allGroups.forEach(function(group){
      tasks.push(deleteFromGroup(group))
    })

    tasks.reduce(function(cur, next) {
      return cur.then(next);
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
     console.log("all executed")
    });
  })
}

function deleteFromGroup(group){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(group.id)
      resolve()
     }, 3000);
  })
}
```

Comment: why have you pasted the answer code into your question?  You shouldn't do that because it destroys context.

Comment: Your code initially didn't work as well and I wanted to ask you why. I found out it was due to my own mistake. I rolled back the question.

Comment: thanks.  Please - never destroy parts of a question that have already had answers posted.

Comment: I won't. Sadly the almighty mods came and marked a percetly fine question as a duplicate...

Comment: @Bergi not really a duplicate IMHO - the OP isn't using Q.

Comment: @Alnitak: That shouldn't matter as it's really exactly the same problem and solution. I can edit the "Q" out of the title if you want :-)

Comment: @Bergi it's _functionally_ the same problem, but the APIs _are_ different.

Comment: @Alnitak and/or Hedge - Just edit the question to include info that makes it clearly unique from the supposed duplicate, and start the re-open cycle. If it's sufficiently differentiated it will be reopened. If not, it remains as a signpost for future users, and is still useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're creating your `tasks` array inevitably results in the timeouts all hitting at (about) the same time, because you're creating the tasks simultaneously in that very first `.forEach` loop.

To achieve the effect you require you need to actually *not create the next task* until the current one is resolved.  Here's a pseudo-recursive way of achieving that:

```
return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    var groups = allGroups.slice(0);  // clone
    (function loop() {
        if (groups.length) {
            deleteFromGroup(groups.shift()).catch(reject).then(loop);
        } else {
            console.log("all executed")
            resolve();
        }
    })();
});
```

p.s. in practise you might actually want to incorporate the 3s timeout directly into the loop, instead of into `deleteFromGroup` - as written the code above (and your original code) won't show "completed" until 3s *after* the final delete call, but I expect it's really supposed to occur immediately at the end.

Comment: Wow, this works amazingly well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to resort to callbacks and explicit construction here. You can in fact use a for loop - but not on the actions since a promise is an already started operation.

All you need to do is merge your two loops:

```
allGroups.reduce(function(cur, next) {
  return cur.then(function(){ return deleteFromGroup(next) });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
 console.log("all executed")
});
```

Comment: I've (probably) fixed the `.catch` case in my answer.  This is kinda funky and I've not personally seen it before, and I do grok it, but I can imagine some folks struggling with this use of `.reduce`

Comment: @Alnitak that might be true, but the OP used reduce in his own code so I assume that's not a problem.